# WPF Images vs. XAML

Tags: wpf, silverlight, performance, image, xaml

When should we use images (jpg, png) and when should we use XAML in an application.

Image

```
+ "easy" for the designer to create what he wants
+ are displayed the same on every computer
- fixed resolution
```

XAML

```
+ vector format (resolution independent, resize able, ...)
+ can be animated
+/- rendered by the client
- not as many effects available as for images or are really complex to create
- complex visual tree
```

I could not find any source, that compares the resource usage (CPU, RAM) between images and XAML.

I personally think everything should be XAML, but I don't want to have an application that is slow as hell. Are there any good performance guidelines for using XAML drawings?

---

Researching this I've read that you should have everything in XAML and then use [RenderTargetBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx) to create static images on demand, but according to this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/06/22/software-rendering-usage-in-wpf.aspx) it will cause the window to be rendered without hardware acceleration. So I'm wondering if it is really an improvement for performance. Ignoring the fact that it is much more work for the coder.

Comment: If you are on modern hardware, I would not worry. XAML might even be faster because you have less disk IO

Comment: I don't see how an image could replace XAML. Images are static and non-interactive...

Comment: I suppose he was talking about icons, buttons, specifically in the case where they are not interactive.

The CPU/RAM resource charge depends on a specific context.
And as you specified before, both have advantages and drawbacks...

If you are just focused on resource consumption, I agree with Wouter Simons :)

Comment: I'm on modern hardware but I don't know about all the users that will use the program. What do you mean with modern 2gHz single core and 1gb RAM or 2,3gHz quad core with 8gb RAM? About the other question: of course I am only talking about the cases where image and xaml is interchangeable like metalcam suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your comment:-

> I am only talking about the cases where image and xaml is interchangeable

Use a PNG, period.  Only use Xaml based imagery when you actually need the advantages it provides.  There may be some edge case exceptions, for example, a large image that can be composed from a couple of simple paths in Xaml. However you would also have to have a good reason to believe that any performance difference is appreciable and worth eliminating.  Ultimately favor simplicity over complexity when the same results are achievable from both.

Comment: You could have eliminated your entire answer, save the last sentence, and it would still be +1.

Answer (score 0):

If your artist/designer can create vector graphics and there are no complex gradients, then I would prefer vector graphics. You get all advantages and no disadvantages.

And if you are concerned about complex visual trees, then WPF offers bitmap caching specifically for these kind of cases.

Comment: On a side note, Expression Blend can import Adobe Illustrator files, which means your graphics designer can create vector graphics in a familiar program that then get rendered using XAML Paths.  It also takes care of importing the gradients for the brushes.